# Union issue in spark dataframes

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have to retrieve data from 3 tables based on some filter and union them.

Sample code:

```scala
Var df1= spark.table(table1).filter(col1='abc').select(col1,col2)

Var df2= spark.table(table2).filter(col1='abc').select(col1,col2)

Var df3= spark.table(table3).filter(col1='abc').select(col1,col2)

Var df4 = df1.union(df2).union(df3)
```

But with the given queries, df2 and df3 will give me 0 records.
While I'm executing the spark job, getting an error like

`User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException : Cannot resolve column name "col1" among();`

How can I rectify this issue?

Comment: It should be either

```import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
var df1= spark.table(table1).filter(col(col1)==="abc").select("col1","col2")```

or

```var df1= spark.table(table1).filter($col1 === "abc").select("col1","col2")```

or you may want to post the snippet with correct syntax and full error stack.

Comment: Try the above posted clue or edit your question and post a neat code and error stack.